# problem in response.getReturnValue() result when storing in two attributes

Tags: lightning-aura-components

When I stored `response.getReturnValue()` in two attributes in lightning if any change applied on one attribute other attribute data also changing

```js
 component.set("v.pricebookProducts", response.getReturnValue()); //getting pricebook  products
 component.set("v.pricebookProductsCopy", response.getReturnValue());
```

if i done any modification on the first attribute then the second attribute also changing.pls help me how to overcome this problem

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because in javascript, if you assign [complex (non-primitive) data-types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures), the assignment is reference types. So, change in copy of data will change the original data also. You can do:

Option 1: [Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

I guess you are returning list of objects (array), so you can do:

```
component.set("v.pricebookProductsCopy", [...response.getReturnValue()]);
```

Option 2: (old method)

```
component.set("v.pricebookProductsCopy", JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response.getReturnValue())));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try deep cloning :

```
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response.getReturnValue()));
```